# I just want to create simple menu links inside some divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to create simple menu links inside some animated divs , the problems is the div disapper if the mous move over the (li) inside it  but if the div empty it works fine ?

first thing just come to my mind is i have to prevent event propagation , so i added this to the elements inside the sum menu ( the (li)) but is still face the same problem.

```js
function hidemneu() {
  $('#submenu1').hide('fold', 'slow');
  $('#submenu2').hide('fold', 'slow');
  $('#submenu3').hide('fold', 'slow');
  $('#submenu4').hide('fold', 'slow');
}

$('#submenu1, #submenu2, #submenu3, #submenu4 ').on('mouseout', hidemneu);

$('#btn1').on('mouseover', function() {
  hidemneu();

  $('#submenu1').offset({

    left: $('#btn1').offset().left
  });


  $('#submenu1').show("fold");


});
$('#btn2').on('mouseover', function() {
  hidemneu();


  $('#submenu2').offset({

    left: $('#btn2').offset().left
  });


  $('#submenu2').show("fold");


});

$('#btn3').on('mouseover', function() {

  hidemneu();

  $('#submenu3').offset({

    left: $('#btn3').offset().left
  });


  $('#submenu3').show("fold");


});


$('#btn4').on('mouseover', function() {

  hidemneu();

  $('#submenu4').offset({

    left: $('#btn4').offset().left
  });


  $('#submenu4').show("fold");


});


$("a").on('mouseover', function(event) {

  event.stopPropagation();

});

$("li").on('mouseover', function(event) {

  event.stopPropagation();

});


$("ul").on('mouseover', function(event) {

  event.stopPropagation();

});
```

```css
#btn1,
#btn2,
#btn3,
#btn4 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff8d73;
  width: 100px;
  outline: 1px dashed #000000;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#menu-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #b7dcff;
  text-align: center;
}
#submenu1,
#submenu2,
#submenu3,
#submenu4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px dashed #000000;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
#submenu1 {
  background-color: #f00700
}
#submenu2 {
  background-color: #a6baf0
}
#submenu3 {
  background-color: #7af044
}
#submenu4 {
  background-color: #f0dc35
}
#sub_wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
}
li,
a {
  outline: 1px dashed #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-wrapper">
  <div id='btn1'>button 1</div>
  <div id='btn2'>button 2</div>
  <div id='btn3'>button 3</div>
  <div id='btn4'>button 4</div>
</div>

<div id="sub_wrapper">
  <div id="submenu1">

    <ul>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>oprion 2</li>

    </ul>
  </div>


  <div id="submenu2">
    <a href="#"> clcik me 1 </a>



  </div>
  <div id="submenu3"></div>
  <div id="submenu4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to stop event prop. Can you clarify the question? When you click #btn1, #submenu1 appears? Then if you click #btn2, it hides #submenu1 and shows #submenu2, is that the idea?

Comment: Actually the  idea is  when click btn1 the submenu1 holds appear, till now evey thing ok and work fine But when i hover in link inside this submenu the whole submnu disappear !! i need this submenu just to dispper if i move out of it , but its do so when even i hover some links inside it !

Comment: When is `hidemneu()` called?

Comment: when the (mouseout of the the div(submenu1) )

Comment: I cant figure out  what is the problem  !  it should be straight forward  job drop down menu ! that set :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing line 8 of the javascript seems to do the trick:

**from:**

```
 $('#submenu1, #submenu2, #submenu3, #submenu4 ').on('mouseout', hidemneu);
```

**to**

```
 $('#submenu1, #submenu2, #submenu3, #submenu4 ').mouseleave(hidemneu);
```

```js
function hidemneu() {
  $('#submenu1').hide('fold', 'slow');
  $('#submenu2').hide('fold', 'slow');
  $('#submenu3').hide('fold', 'slow');
  $('#submenu4').hide('fold', 'slow');
}

$('#submenu1, #submenu2, #submenu3, #submenu4 ').mouseleave(hidemneu);

$('#btn1').on('mouseover', function() {
  hidemneu();

  $('#submenu1').offset({

    left: $('#btn1').offset().left
  });


  $('#submenu1').show("fold");


});
$('#btn2').on('mouseover', function() {
  hidemneu();


  $('#submenu2').offset({

    left: $('#btn2').offset().left
  });


  $('#submenu2').show("fold");


});

$('#btn3').on('mouseover', function() {

  hidemneu();

  $('#submenu3').offset({

    left: $('#btn3').offset().left
  });


  $('#submenu3').show("fold");


});


$('#btn4').on('mouseover', function() {

  hidemneu();

  $('#submenu4').offset({

    left: $('#btn4').offset().left
  });


  $('#submenu4').show("fold");


});


$("a").on('mouseover', function(event) {

  event.stopPropagation();

});

$("li").on('mouseover', function(event) {

  event.stopPropagation();

});


$("ul").on('mouseover', function(event) {

  event.stopPropagation();

});
```

```css
#btn1,
#btn2,
#btn3,
#btn4 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff8d73;
  width: 100px;
  outline: 1px dashed #000000;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#menu-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #b7dcff;
  text-align: center;
}
#submenu1,
#submenu2,
#submenu3,
#submenu4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px dashed #000000;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
#submenu1 {
  background-color: #f00700
}
#submenu2 {
  background-color: #a6baf0
}
#submenu3 {
  background-color: #7af044
}
#submenu4 {
  background-color: #f0dc35
}
#sub_wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
}
li,
a {
  outline: 1px dashed #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-wrapper">
  <div id='btn1'>button 1</div>
  <div id='btn2'>button 2</div>
  <div id='btn3'>button 3</div>
  <div id='btn4'>button 4</div>
</div>

<div id="sub_wrapper">
  <div id="submenu1">

    <ul>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>oprion 2</li>

    </ul>
  </div>


  <div id="submenu2">
    <a href="#"> clcik me 1 </a>



  </div>
  <div id="submenu3"></div>
  <div id="submenu4"></div>
</div>
```